# Serverless issue with AWS Lambda and Open CV in Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, opencv, aws-lambda, serverless

I am developing a microservice to analyze an image uploaded to an S3 AWS Bucket. I am using Serverless framework. I am using virtualenv to install the dependencies with PIP and serverless-python-requirements plugin to deploy these dependencies to the Lambda function.

However I am having an error when I deploy the microservice because of a missing .so file. The error I get is

*Unable to import module 'handlers.image': libgthread-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file*

My serverless.yml file is

```
service: sls-covid

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.8
  profile: testuser
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'staging'}
  environment: ${file(environment.yml):${self:provider.stage}}
  region: ${self:provider.environment.REGION}

  iamRoleStatements:
    # para poder leer y escribir en el bucket
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - "s3:*"
      Resource: "*"

custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: non-linux


package:
  individually: true
  exclude:
    - node_modules/**
    - env/**
    - package.json
    - package-lock.json

functions:

  analyzeImage:
    # para analizar la imagen cuando se almacena en S3
    handler: handlers.image.analyze
    events:
      - s3:
          bucket: ${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}-images
          event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
          rules:
            - prefix: uploads/

plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements
```

The relevant code is:

```
import json
import logging
import boto3
from pydicom import dcmread
import numpy as np
# here the code stops working
import cv2
from pydicom.filebase import DicomBytesIO

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

s3 = boto3.client('s3')


def analyze(event, context):

    print("=== event: ", event)

    # code to read uploaded image from bucket and create a ds object 

    # code below is never executed since the error appears when the cv2 library is loaded  

    img = cv2.resize(ds.pixel_array, (224, 224))
```

And my requirements.txt contents is as follows:

```
numpy==1.18.4
opencv-python==4.2.0.34
pandas==1.0.3
pydicom==1.4.2
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2018.7
six==1.14.0
```

My question is. How can I properly upload opencv dependencies to my lambda function using the plugin? Should I do this in another way?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you outline the process a bit please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the [doc](https://github.com/UnitedIncome/serverless-python-requirements#native-code-dependencies-during-runtime), you need to include those manually using `dockerExtraFiles` option.

======================= UPDATE =======================

Packaging Python dependencies and building deployment package for AWS Lambda can be quite tricky. After digging around, here are the things that you need to do to make it work.

#### Step 1: Add a `Dockerfile`

```
FROM lambci/lambda:build-python3.8
RUN yum -y install libXext libSM libXrender
```

#### Step 2: Modify `serverless.yml`

```
service: sls-covid

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.8
  profile: testuser
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'staging'}
  environment: ${file(environment.yml):${self:provider.stage}}
  region: ${self:provider.environment.REGION}

  iamRoleStatements:
    # para poder leer y escribir en el bucket
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - "s3:*"
      Resource: "*"

custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: non-linux
    ########### BEGIN ###########
    dockerFile: Dockerfile
    dockerExtraFiles:
      - /lib64/libgthread-2.0.so.0
      - /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0
      - /lib64/libSM.so.6
      - /lib64/libICE.so.6
      - /lib64/libXrender.so.1
      - /lib64/libXext.so.6
      - /lib64/libX11.so.6
      - /lib64/libuuid.so.1
      - /lib64/libxcb.so.1
      - /lib64/libXau.so.6
    ########### END ###########


package:
  individually: true
  exclude:
    - node_modules/**
    - env/**
    - package.json
    - package-lock.json

functions:

  analyzeImage:
    # para analizar la imagen cuando se almacena en S3
    handler: handlers.image.analyze
    events:
      - s3:
          bucket: ${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}-images
          event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
          rules:
            - prefix: uploads/

plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements
```

#### Step 3: Hello world testing

```
$ sls invoke -f analyzeImage --log
null
--------------------------------------------------------------------
START RequestId: 00ccd940-cf8a-46ed-8671-65e597f997a0 Version: $LATEST
=== event:  {}
END RequestId: 00ccd940-cf8a-46ed-8671-65e597f997a0
REPORT RequestId: 00ccd940-cf8a-46ed-8671-65e597f997a0  Duration: 1.41 ms   Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 1024 MB    Max Memory Used: 121 MB Init Duration: 916.32 ms
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi. I added that specific file from my computer and the error remains.

Comment: @Jonathan I've updated my answer. Please take a look.

Comment: thanks! It worked great! I struggled still a bit because of the cache. It results that in /home/user/.cache/serverless-python-requirements/ there are some dirs with the cache. I had to delete these files so that the Dockerfile changes took effect. 

Thanks a lot!

Comment: As another note. When the dockerExtraFiles are being properly loaded you can see their names in the serverless console after you run sls deploy.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. what i adventually do is:

1. develop on ec2 linux instance. this is way easier, because you run into all errors while developing before deploying.
2. find the missing .so file. find . -name "libgthread-2.0.so.0"
3. make a dir named lib in project home named "lib". this folder is included in LD_LIBRARY_PATH.
4. copy the required libgthread-2.0.so.0  file into lib folder.
5. sls deploy.
   now the missing .so file is found.